# Sculpting brushes other than the grab brushes aren't affecting most of my mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, sculpting

[image]All of the blue and red/orange brushes aren't doing anything when applied to the upper part of my hair object mesh. I've tried flipping the normals and recalculating them, didn't change it. Trying it with dynamic topology off also didn't fix it. The brushes seem to occasionally work on the bottom part of my mesh, and I went inside of the mesh once and the inflate brush worked from the inside out.

[blend file uploaded to google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C6_8_cUYYsw9tvResdKGe-U8ZoIcWT7Z/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I uploaded a picture of the mesh but unless I made a gif of the issue happening there really isn't anything of value a still image could add, other than if someone wanted a picture of a specific settings menu or statistics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to object mode, select the mesh, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then choose Scale.

here more info: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/clear_apply.html#apply-object-transformations

[Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)

this is the problem: negative scale (and not uniform)
[image]